# Why do forms of address differ depending of the type of politician?

Tags: questions, figure-of-speech, titles

In English, why do we say Mr. President/Mrs. President but not Mr. King/Mrs. Queen?

My first language is French, and the same principle applies. What I mean is in French, we say *Monsieur le Président/Madame la Présidente*, but not *Monsieur le Roi/Madame la Reine*.

Also, why do we say Your Majesty/Your Highness for a monarch (king/queen/prince/princess/emperor/empress/sultan), but Your Excellency for a president/prime minister?

Comment: There is a difference between politicians, especially elected ones, and nobility like kings and princes, who are officially high in status, and need to be flattered with polite speech, like plural 2nd persons and third persons -- not *_Mr. Majesty_ but _Your Majesty, vouvoyer, Siezen,_ etc.

Comment: I think terms of office carry no inherent politeness, so you need to add Mr./Madame/etc. to show courtesy.  Terms of nobility are inherently polite; however, to show extra courtesy you address one of their attributes, rather than the person, like "majesty," "eminence," etc.  Protocol/étiquette eventually dictated which terms were appropriate for which title in each language and country.  For example, in English, I think ambassadors are addressed with "your excellence," kings and queens with "your majesty," and princes and princesses with "your (royal) highness."

Comment: In Spanish, Portuguese, and Japanese, the tendency to address the status of the person, rather than the person directly, became so pervasive that some of the terms are now used as regular pronouns with third-person verbs, sometimes in reduced form.  For example, "usted" in Spanish comes from "vuestra merced" ("your (pl) mercy").  O Senhor/A Senhora ("the lord/lady") is a formal form of "you" in Portuguese.  In Japanese 貴様 (kisama) ("honored status/appearance/situation") started off a few hundred years ago as a form of honorable address, but has deteriorated into a pejorative form of address."

Comment: I recall that there was some debate in the US early on as to how to speak about the president. I believe Mr. was chosen as it would not create the sense of nobility or title. The Federalist party may have at times tried to use something fancier since they liked some of the trappings of monarchy but surely once the Republicans took over, that would have been gone.

Comment: In British English, we do not usually use Mr/Mrs/Ms when addressing politicians by their role: interviewers either use their names, or address them as _Minister_, _Secretary of State_, _Prime Minister_.

Comment: Like when they changed to title of _Yes, Minister_ to _Yes, Prime Minister_. The whole TV world got a lesson on RP vocatives.